# Cypher Query: - Allow apostrope(') containing String in the query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

We are creating query in our code by concatenating strings in the syntax of the query like to create a node all the properties in the query are added at run time.

> The query is like this in the code where
>
> nodeLabel =String
>
> properties = JSONObject

```
String query = "CREATE (n:" + nodeLabel + "{" + properties
                    + "}) RETURN n";
```

**Error executing query create** `(n:quiz{name:"1506077464525",createtime:1506077464525,title:"bernoulli's theory",duration:15,privacy:"follower",status:"draft"}) return n with params {}`
because its not allowing apostrophe(') in the query in the java code.

The same query is executing on the  neo4j browser but the same query is not executing when trying through code.

How to resolve this issue and allow for the same.

---

**Problem 2 :-**  Same issue occurring with updating the property of the node.

I tried to code but its giving me error of serialization.

```
Connection connect = null;
    int status = 00;
    try {
        connect = graphdbConnect();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object key : propertiesMap.keySet()) {

            if (sb.length() != 0) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
                sb.append("n." + key + " = " + propertiesMap.get(key));

                System.out.println(sb);
        }

        String query = "match (n{name:'" + nodeName + "'}) set {1}"
                + " return n.name";

        query=query.toLowerCase();

        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query)){

            preparedStatement.setObject(1,sb);
            System.out.println(query+" ---> query");
            preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            status = ServerStatusReport.OK();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

> Error:-Error executing query match (n{name:'1506160405300'}) set n.{1}
>   return n.name  with params {1=n.title = Asjdkjsbd's}  at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.executeQuery(Neo4jConnection.java:372)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Neo4jPreparedStatement.java:46)
>     at
>   com.edubot.server.Neo4jQueries.updateNodeProperty1(Neo4jQueries.java:622)
>     at
>   com.edubot.server.course.CourseNeo4jQueries.updateCourseTitle(CourseNeo4jQueries.java:490)
>     at
>   com.edubot.server.course.CourseServiceImpl.updateCourseTitle(CourseServiceImpl.java:1215)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
>     at com.edubot.server.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:51)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize value 1
>   n.title = Asjdkjsbd's     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.JsonUtils.serialize(JsonUtils.java:101)   at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Statement.toJson(Statement.java:48)   at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Statement.toJson(Statement.java:68)   at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.TransactionalQueryExecutor.post(TransactionalQueryExecutor.java:112)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.TransactionalQueryExecutor.commit(TransactionalQueryExecutor.java:135)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.TransactionalQueryExecutor.executeQueries(TransactionalQueryExecutor.java:198)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.TransactionalQueryExecutor.executeQuery(TransactionalQueryExecutor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.executeQuery(Neo4jConnection.java:363)
>     ... 38 more

Comment: Can you include the actual error message? And is that query the printout of the Cypher your code generates? I provided an answer that should catch all " ' problems in Cypher Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For labels, use backticks (`) as described by the [docs on label names](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#_label_names).
2. You can you pack the properties to a Java map and [pass it as a parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-create-node-with-properties). If you are using the Java driver, here is [how to pass parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementRunner.html#run-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-).

   Note that the parameter syntax changed in version 3.2 - the Parameters docs page has more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I use to convert a string into a Cypher-safe quoted string. The way you are doing it is vulnerable to injection. This should catch whatever the actual error in your code is.

```
if (!str.contains("\"")) {
    str= '"' + str + '"';
} else if (!str.contains("'")) {
    str= "'" + str + "'";
} else {
    str= '"' + str.replaceAll("\"", "\"+'\"'+\"").replaceAll("\\+\"\"|\"\"\\+", "") + '"';
}
```